# Is it possible to display numbers in the form of infinitely repeating decimal fractions $0. \bar{1}$ as ticks in a plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame, continued-fractions

I want to show the infinitely repeating decimal fractions in these explicit forms $0. \bar{1}$ and $0. \bar{2}$ as `Thicks` in a plot; is it possible to do that?

If the code for `Thicks` is as  `FrameTicks -> {{{0.1 , 0.2}, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`, how should I modify/change `{0.1 , 0.2}` to have those `OverBar` on $1$ and $2$?

Thanks for any comments in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You could also use the [`ResourceFunction`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) for [`"RecurringDecimalForm"`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RecurringDecimalForm)

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {{#, ResourceFunction["RecurringDecimalForm"][#]} & /@
     Range[0, 1, 1/9], None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[
    x
    , {x, 0.09, 0.23}
    , PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "LargeLabels"}
    , FrameTicks -> {
        {
            {
                0.1,
                { 1/9, Row[{"0.",OverBar[1]}] },
                0.2,
                { 2/9, Row[{"0.",OverBar[2]}] }
            }
            , Automatic
        }
        , Automatic
    }
]
```

[image]